# How to extract date from database using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I'm trying to create a weekly work schedule. When I try to select the shifts from the database my date value is selecting the current time but the date (Y-m-d) from the table.

This is my code:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
          $dt = new DateTime();
          $dt->setISODate($year, $week);

          $fetch_mID = $row['ID_EMPLOYEE'];
          $fetch_fn = $row['Firstname'];
          $fetch_en = $row['Lastname'];
          echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $fetch_fn . " " . $fetch_en . "</td>";

            do {
              $obj = new ReflectionObject($dt);
              $pro = $obj->getProperty('date');
              $date = $pro->getValue($dt);
              echo $date; //Output = 'Y-m-d H:m:s'

              $shift = $conn->query("SELECT ShiftDate, ShiftStart, ShiftEnd FROM shifts WHERE ID_EMPLOYEE = '$fetch_mID' AND Date(ShiftDate) = '$date'");
              $fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($shift);
              $dt->modify('+1 day');
            } while ($week == $dt->format('W'));
```

I would expect the $date to output Y-m-d but it outputs Y-m-d H:m:s. And the time is the current time.

Comment: can you check what is the type of **$date** ? using  **gettype($date)**

Comment: It is a string.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: So, why `$dt = new DateTime(); $obj = new ReflectionObject($dt); $pro = $obj->getProperty('date'); $date = $pro->getValue($dt); echo $date;` instead of just `$date = $dt->format("Y-m-d");`?

Comment: @miken32, It is faster than format(). Especially since it is in a loop.

Comment: Even if that were true, it is an exceedingly pointless microoptimization for the complexity it introduces to your code. If you're that worried about speed, you'd be better off switching your code to use prepared statements, which would give you other benefits as well.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/p5pmG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to convert **$date** to date object and then format the date with the new format **Y-m-d**.

```
  $time = strtotime($date);
  $newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);
  echo $newformat; // output 2019-04-05
```

You new code seems to b something like :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
          $dt = new DateTime();
          $dt->setISODate($year, $week);

          $fetch_mID = $row['ID_EMPLOYEE'];
          $fetch_fn = $row['Firstname'];
          $fetch_en = $row['Lastname'];
          echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $fetch_fn . " " . $fetch_en . "</td>";

            do {
              $obj = new ReflectionObject($dt);
              $pro = $obj->getProperty('date');
              $date = $pro->getValue($dt);
              //new code
              $newformat = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
              echo $newformat; // output 2019-04-05
              // end new code
              $shift = $conn->query("SELECT ShiftDate, ShiftStart, ShiftEnd FROM shifts WHERE ID_EMPLOYEE = '$fetch_mID' AND Date(ShiftDate) = '$date'");
              $fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($shift);
              $dt->modify('+1 day');
            } while ($week == $dt->format('W'));
```

Comment: Might wanna remove the extra `;` in `date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date););` = `date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));`

Comment: Thank you. The output is now the correct format but it still doesn't select the values from the table.

Comment: what is the type of ShiftDate  in the db ?

Comment: Nevermind. Just had to change the $date in the select to $newformat. You have my love. Many thanks.

Comment: Use `DateTime` class

Comment: for the sql selectio , i think that the  the Date(ShiftDate) format is not the same as $date . check the format of Date(ShiftDate) . may be you have to make  $newformat instead of $date in the query in case that Date(ShiftDate) has the format "Y-m-d"